# Filenet - Get Email Id out of user id in Filenet Workflow

Tags: filenet-content-engine, filenet-process-engine, content-platform-engine

I am new to Filenet BPM and I am working on an approval system workflow where an attached document is either approved Or rejected based on the response. I have to send an email to Originator that the document is approved Or rejected and I am able to fetch the userId/AliasId of a person who launched the workflow but I am unable to get the emailId out of a userid. We already had an LDAP configuration settings at domain level but I don't know what should I do to achieve this functionality. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `com.filenet.api.security.User`:

```
User user = Factory.User.fetchInstance(connection, userId, null);
String email = user.get_Email();
```

`userId` may be in different forms, as noted in [the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/com/filenet/api/core/Factory.User.html#fetchInstance%28com.filenet.api.core.Connection,%20java.lang.String,%20com.filenet.api.property.PropertyFilter%29):

> Valid strings are the Id, the short name, or the distinguished name.
>   If the authentication provider is Microsoft Active Directory, you can
>   also specify the UPN.